# MVC Mapping ViewModel only works with int

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

Here is a section of my controller code:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

var model = new IndexViewModel
{
    HasPassword = HasPassword(),
    PhoneNumber = await UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(userId),
    TwoFactor = await UserManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(userId),
    Logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(userId),
    BrowserRemembered = await AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(userId),
    CC = db.Users.Single(x => x.Id == userId).CC
};

return View(model);
```

The following line only works when `CC` is of type `int`:

```
CC = db.Users.Single(x => x.Id == userId).CC
```

When `CC` is a `string`, I get the error below:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This begs the question, why would you use a string field for an int value - what does `CC` contain?

Answer (score 2):

To be honest this really have nothing to do with MVC or models - it's just a basic C# problem.

You're trying to assign an `int` variable into something that only takes a `string`. If you want to convert an `int` into a `string`, call `ToString`:

```
CC = db.Users.Single(x => x.Id == userId).CC.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

If property always return number data then probably you will be need to convert into the int

```
CC = Int32.Parse(db.Users.Single(x => x.Id == userId).CC);
```

By the way if CC contains integer value then its data type also should be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out. There was a glitch somewhere - I'm not sure where - CC was originally an int and then was changed to type string and after that it would not work. I have updated db and everything needed but it was still not working until complete pc reboot - after that is started working fine.